# gulp-nodemon watch typescript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, nodemon

I have 2 directories:

- app `es5 javascript files compiled by gulp task`
- src `typescript source files`

I want to nodemon make start script from `app/` restart on any changes in `src/` dir. But it doesn't work - App just started, but nodemon doesn't make any reloads on changes. (Looks like he doesn't watch `src/`)

This is my `gulpfile`:

```
var gulp = require("gulp-help")(require("gulp")),
    ts = require("gulp-typescript"),
    nodemon = require("gulp-nodemon");

/***********************************************************************************
 * Build es5 javascript files from typescript sources
 ***********************************************************************************/
gulp.task("compile", function() {
    var project = ts.createProject({
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    });
    return gulp.src("./src/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(project())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./app/"))
});

/***********************************************************************************
 * Call "build" task and start nodemon with watch (autorestart on changes found)
 ***********************************************************************************/
gulp.task("default", ["compile"], function() {
    var stream = nodemon({
        script: "app/",
        watch: "src",
        tasks: ["compile"],
        env: { "DEBUG": "Application,Request,Response" }
    });
    return stream;
});
```

Comment: you can use gulp.watch, imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the provided code you are missing the starting file for script:

The Following  `script: "app/"` needs to be specified to an actual file not a directory.

**For example**:

*Note: make sure you are using the compiled .js file and not a .ts file for the nodemon server.*

```
script : 'app.js'
```

or you can put a path to make sure you are in the correct location.

```
script : 'app/app.js
```

What this does it starts the server using the specified file. If this does not work I recommend looking at your file structure, in specific where the gulpfile.js file is located. Depending on the location you might not be using the correct path.

Answer (score -14):

You have to use mysql for the php and grub section for the perl and chmod options